# При нажатии F5 просит повторно отправить введенные данные

Tags: php

Как избавиться от этого? Что и куда надо вписать?

Answer (score 0):

обнуляй request после отправки

Comment: Я не отправляю. Я сделал кнопку, при нажатии на которую я перехожу на другую страницу. И вот на ней при нажатии на F5 просит отправлять какие-то введенные данные.

Answer (score 0):

Используй редирект с [302](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302) после приёма формы.

Comment: Можете описать подробнее, как это сделать? Я новичок, и никак не могу найти информацию по этому поводу.